# How to auto refresh PHP session variables

Tags: php, sql

I have sql field called seen - it’s either yes or
No.

This seen field is in my user table.

When user logs in I am saving this seen status to session variable.

Page checks which user is logged in, and if they have Value of yes in seen field, page shows one picture, value of no shoes another picture.

My issue: let’s say I have ‘no’ for a user for seen field and page shows one picture, then I go into database and change value to ‘yes’ for seen.. the image doesn’t change.

If I log out and then back in, then it changes. But not automatically when changed on back end.

Question: is there a way, to where if value is changed on backend, that session variable will auto update with this new value?

Comment: No, there is no way to *auto* update.  (Depending on the definition of "auto" that is... For example, you could write your own custom framework for this purpose and configure it to "automatically" perform logic that you write into the framework.  But either way, in order for the system to do something you, or someone, has to write code to do it.)  You can, however, update the value any time you like.  Have you tried updating the value?  What didn't work?